# How to sort first half of an array in ascending order and second half in descending order

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, merge

I currently have a Merge Sort algorithm up using Java but I am struggling with modifying it to sort the second half in descending order. It should also have a time complexity of O(n).

For example:

Input:  34, 12, 7, 43, 55, 97, 41, 28, 2, 62

Output: 2, 7, 12, 28, 34, 97, 62, 55, 43, 41

Comment: Sort the array, and then reverse the second half. Reversing an array is O(n). The initial sort is O(nlogn). So performing the reverse step after finishing the sort has no effect on the time complexity, and little effect on the run time.

Comment: (It should be (one iteration) faster to order the halves individually. And you could obviate the reversal.)

Answer (score 0):

In java 1.8+ we can do it like this. we can optimize it further. :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream<Integer> streamObj = Stream.of(34, 12, 7, 43, 55, 97, 41, 28, 2, 62);
    List<Integer> list1 = streamObj.collect(Collectors.toList());
    int middleIndex = list1.size()/2;
    System.out.println(middleIndex);
    List<Integer> firstHalf = list1.subList(0,middleIndex).stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Integer> secondHalf = list1.subList(middleIndex,list1.size()).stream().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println("firstHalf"+firstHalf+"\nsecondHalf"+secondHalf);
    firstHalf.addAll(secondHalf);
    System.out.println(firstHalf);
}
```